# RingTone key is not found from onSharedPreferenceChanged method

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm learning how to use Preferences in Android. I have a small a application on which I want to set a series of preferences which includes a `RingTonePreference`. My `activity` implements  `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`  and override the  `onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key)` method  to handle all the different preferences.

Until the `ringtone` one everything was working fine. My problem seems to be that the `key` of the `ringTonePreference` is not found and my code never enters the `if` statement of the `ringTonePreference`.

Here is my `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method:

```
 public class preferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {  
    // code here


@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {

    if (key.equals("list_subject_pref")) {
        // do something
    } else if (key.equals("et_subject_pref")) {
                    // do something
    } else if (key.equals("list_times_pref")) {
        // do something

            // here is problem, it never enters the if statement why?
    } else if (key.equals("ringtonePref")) {
        RingtonePreference preference = (RingtonePreference) findPreference("ringtonePref");
        preference.setSummary("ringtone selected");
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my `preferences.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/subjectpreferences" >
    <ListPreference
        android:key="list_subject_pref"
        // other stuff here/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:key="et_subject_pref"
         // other stuff here />

    <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:key="list_times_pref"
        // other stuff here />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/reminderpreferences" >
    <RingtonePreference
        android:key="ringtonePref"
        android:showDefault="true"
        android:showSilent="true"
        android:summary="Select a ringtone"
        android:title="Ringtones" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="preference_ringtonereminder"
        android:summary="summary"
        android:summaryOff="@string/remindme_off"
        android:summaryOn="@string/remindme_on"
        android:title="@string/reminderringtone_title" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725105/ringtonepreference-not-firing-onsharedpreferencechanged) but I'm still not able to fix my problem.